# Firestore - disallow reading multiple documents at once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

- I've got a Firestore collection.
- The IDs of the documents are secrets. You should be able to read only the document whose ID you know.
  *For the sake of simplicity. I'd like to stick to this approach.*
- However, by default, one can read an entire collection from Firestore, for example

```
await firestore.collection("secret_documents").get()
```

**Is it possible to allow reading only one document at once, only when it's referred by its ID?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is actually quite easy. To control what documents can be accessed, use Firebase [security rules for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

By default your security rules will be `read` and `write`, but those can actually be broken down into more [granular operations of `get`, `list`, `create` and `update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations). And what you're trying to do is to allow `get`, but not a `list` operation. From the documentation:

> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // A read rule can be divided into get and list rules
>     match /cities/{city} {
>       // Applies to single document read requests
>       allow get: if <condition>;
>
>      // Applies to queries and collection read requests
>       allow list: if <condition>;
>     }
>     ...
> ```

So to allow `get` for everyone and disallow `list` calls:

```
allow get: if true;
allow list: if false;
```

You'll probably want to elaborate on the `allow get` rule a bit, because it's more common to restrict it, for example to users that are signed in to your project with Firebase Authentication:

```
allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works for web and mobile client SDKs.  Server SDKs bypass rules entirely.